# Google Contacts API v3: how to use full text query?

Tags: google-contacts-api

I cannot seem to get a search of Google Contacts using a query parameter to work.

I can successfully authenticate the user, get a list of Contacts Groups, and get a list of contacts within a group, but cannot get a search to work.

From the documentation, I'd assume that my URI would have to look something like this to do a search for "tracy" in the default user's contacts (assuming I've already been authenticated via OAuth2):

> https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/default/full?q=tracy

However, I get a "Bad Request" response (_rc = 400)

I suppose that I could download all the contacts and then do the search myself, but I can't imagine there's no way for GOOGLE(!) to do this search on the server.

Any help greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem with the `q` parameter being ignored. I had to add version parameter, `v=3.0`, for the `q` to be recognized as illustrated by [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-contacts-api/-wno8woy6dw).

Your full URL should be:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?q=tracy&v=3.0
```

Note the corrected URL as mentioned by Blake O.

For my use, I also added the `access_token` parameter that I get after `gapi.auth.authorize` from the Google API Client JS library

Comment: Is it required to add version even If I use Java library of contact api 3.0 ??

Comment: Hmm, I don't know. I haven't used the Java library. Can you report your results here? TIA

Answer (score 1):

Bad URL.

www.google.com/m8/feeds/**contacts**/default/full?q=tracy

Comment: DOH!  you're right.  i figured this out myself sometime ago.  it's crazy how many times one can look at code and JUST.NOT.SEE.ERRORS. thanks!